# react native get available text tracks

Tags: android, react-native, subtitle, react-native-video

i'm using react-native-video to play **mp4 ** videos , and they can have embed subtitles , i need to show list of available subtitles , and select one of them , how i can do that ?

```
                        <Video
                        source={
                            require('../../_assets/video.mp4')
                        }
                        ref={ref => (this.$player = ref)}
                        style={styles.fullScreen}
                        paused={pause}
                        posterResizeMode={'cover'}
                        seek={1000}
                        playInBackground={false}
                        onProgress={onProgress}
                        repeat={true}
                        onLoad={onLoad}
                        onSeek={onSeek}
                        renderToHardwareTextureAndroid/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution , onLoad data argument containing extisting textracks

Answer (score 1):

Use TextTracks from react-native-video. you can find out more about it [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video#texttracks). You can then pass the subtitles as a prop to the video component. Should work out of the box after that.